# CFC Bind Not Working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, coldfusion, cfc

I have a form in my application that has three input fields which have values populated from queries in a CFC.

The first field is a CFSELECT list of values that are returned via a BIND call from the CFC. Once a value is selected, the other two CFINPUT fields are updated accordingly via a BIND call to the same CFC. Pretty straight forward.

Everything works as planned in Google Chrome and Safari but does not in Firefox. In Firefox, my CFSELECT list is empty and subsequently none of my other 2 CFINPUT fields contain any values as a result.

I have not tried in IE but that browser is not a planned supported broswer anyways for this app we are creating. But I never had an incompatibility like this before with Firefox, ussually just with IE.

Is there something I'm missing?

**Here is my Form**

```
<cfform name="addmileage" id="addmileage" method="post" class="vehicle-log-form">
             <br />
<table border="0" cellpadding="5">
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Service Vehicle:</label></td>
                        <td><cfselect class="vehicle-log-form" queryPosition="below" name="vehicle_name" id="vehicle_name" value="vehicle_name" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getData()" bindonload="true" >
                        </cfselect>                    </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Date:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="tripCalendarInputBox" name="vdate" id="vdate" type="text" required="yes" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <label class="vehicle-log-form">Origin:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" required="yes" name="origin" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Destination:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput required="yes"  class="vehicle-log-form" name="destination" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr><!---onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getDetail({vehicle_name})" bindattribute="value" bindonload="true" ---> 
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Start Odometer:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" id="start_odometer"  name="start_odometer" type="text"  onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getDetail({vehicle_name})" bindattribute="value" bindonload="true"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr><!---onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getDetail({vehicle_name})" bindattribute="value" bindonload="true" --->
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">End Odometer:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form"  id="end_odometer" name="end_odometer" type="text"  onBlur="stopMaterialCalc();" onFocus="startOdometerCalc();" bind="cfc:cfcs.mileagedata.getDetail({vehicle_name})" bindattribute="value" bindonload="true"/></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Total mileage:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" id="total_mileage" name="total_mileage" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label class="vehicle-log-form">Expenses:</label></td>
                        <td><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" value="0.00" name="expenses" type="text" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">

                       <cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Trip">
                                         <br /><cfform>
```

**Here is my CFC**

```
  <!---Service Vehicle Slect Box --->
<cffunction name="getData" access="remote" returntype="query">
    <cfoutput>
    <!--- Function to get data from datasource --->
    <!---Get Service Vehicles --->
    <cfquery name="data" datasource="#datasource#">
    select vehicle_name
    from vehicles
    where active = '1'
    </cfquery>
    </cfoutput>

    <!--- Return results --->
    <cfreturn data>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDetail" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="vehicle_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var dataDetail = "">
    <cfoutput>
    <cfquery name="dataDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT mileage
        FROM   vehicles
        <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
        WHERE vehicle_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.vehicle_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfreturn dataDetail.mileage>
</cffunction></cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work in firefox? are any errors occurring? have you looked through the console?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work in Firefox. That is the purpose of me posting this question. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: My point is you have to do more debugging. It's very unlikely that anyone is going to be able to look over your code and find a reason for it to not work in firefox when most of the work is being done by coldfusion in this case.

Comment: Start by looking through the network tab and comparing it to the network tab in chrome. In order to fix a problem, you first need to know what the problem is.

Comment: A big part of the problem is that you are using `cfform` and `cfselect` rather than doing it the right way with libraries such as jQuery or Ext.

Comment: You have invalid HTML for starters, which can't be helping: `<td colspan="2"><cfinput class="vehicle-log-form" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add Trip"><br /><cfform>`  Where's your closing `</td></tr></table>`?

Comment: Also you don't need to wrap `<cfquery>` inside `<cfoutput>`